# why defining only __lt__ makes > operation possible?

Tags: python, class, operator-keyword, gt

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self._a=a
        self._b=b
    def __lt__(self,other):
        return self._a<other._a


a=Node(1,2)
b=Node(0,4)
print(a>b)
```

The code above shows True.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self._a=a
        self._b=b
    def __lt__(self,other):
        return self._a<other._a
    def __eq__(self,other):
        return self._a==other._a

a=Node(1,2)
b=Node(0,4)
print(a>=b)
```

The code above shows TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'Node' and 'Node.

Why defining only **lt** makes >(which is **gt**) operation possible?
why defining both **lt** and **eq** makes <= impossible?

Comment: Read https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__) dictates:

> There are no swapped-argument versions of these methods (to be used when the left argument does not support the operation but the right argument does); rather, `__lt__()` and `__gt__()` are each other’s reflection, `__le__()` and `__ge__()` are each other’s reflection, and `__eq__()` and `__ne__()` are their own reflection.

So if the left-hand-side argument doesn't implement a comparison operator while the right-hand-side implements its reflection, that reflection is called instead. This also explains why Python doesn't combine `__lt__()` and `__eq__()` into `__le__()` — it simply isn't considered.

Answer (score -1):

In the first example you are comparing with `>`, which uses `__gt__`. In the second example you are comparing with `>=`, which is a different comparison, and it uses `__ge__`.

Have a look at [rich comparison](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__) at the docs

> These are the so-called “rich comparison” methods. The correspondence
> between operator symbols and method names is as follows: `x<y` calls
> `x.__lt__(y)`, `x<=y` calls `x.__le__(y)`, `x==y` calls `x.__eq__(y)`, `x!=y`
> calls `x.__ne__(y)`, `x>y` calls `x.__gt__(y)`, and `x>=y` calls `x.__ge__(y)`.

Comment: from doc: ```lt(a, b) is equivalent to a < b```

Comment: @iperov where exactly? please share the link.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/operator.html

Comment: @iperov you are looking in the wrong docs, the question is about `__lt__` functionality in a class, not `operator` library.

Comment: `x<y calls x.__lt__(y)` https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__

Comment: @iperov I know, its in my answer.

Comment: your answer is ```>, which uses __lt__``` that is wrong.